# How to make real abbreviated units' style for DateComponentsFormatter?

Tags: swift, foundation

For English language `.abbreviated` `unitsStyle` works as expected. It has no extra spaces, only contains one or two letters per unit, and looks like that: 10m 5s

For German for some reason it looks different, it is now three letters for minutes: 10min 5s

For Russian it looks even stranger, it also adds unnecessary spaces: 10 мин 5 с

It really ruins the idea of a short date which can be useful when there is not much space for a label on the screen.

Why is it behaving so strangely? And is there a way to make it work as expected: no extra spaces, smallest amount of letters possible.

Here is the code you can play with in playground:

```
import Foundation

func formatSeconds(_ seconds: TimeInterval) -> String {
    var calendar = Calendar.current
    calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru")
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.calendar = calendar
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    return formatter.string(from: seconds)!
}

formatSeconds(605)
```

Comment: It's not strange. Those are the standards for a given locale. Something like "10m 5s" might not make any sense in German, for example (I don't know German so I can't confirm but the locale specific formatting isn't random).

Comment: @rmaddy well I as a native Russian speaker, would totally understand "10м 5с". I wonder if there is some kind of official standards document we could look at?

Comment: In countries using the metric system “m” is the abbreviation for meter and not minute, that might be the reason.